# pre-compilation message in C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, compiler-warnings, avr, atmega

I'm writing a function that configures external interrupts in ATMEGA32 using C language

```
    typedef enum{
        LOW_LVL,
        CHANGE,
        FALLING,
        RISING
        }TRIGGER;

    void configExtInt(uint8_t ExtIntNo, TRIGGER trig){
        sei();
        if (ExtIntNo == INT0){

        }else if (ExtIntNo == INT1){

        }else if (ExtIntNo == INT2){

        }else{
            cli();
        /* warning message here*/
        }
    }
```

I want to display a warning message during compilation in case the user of my function provided parameter other than INT0, INT1, INT2 to my function.

For example :

```
configExtInt (INT3, FALLING);
```

Is that possible?

Comment: I highly doubt adding a compiler warning for that situation is possible. There might be function calls where ExtIntNo is a user input, ora random value, or anything else not known at compile time. Maybe you can change the code to use C defines which are evaluated during compile time?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The text "a warning message during compilation in case they didn't INT0, INT1, or INT2" is unclear. Who are they? what did they not do? I think it's important to clarify this.

Comment: @anatolyg
They refers to whoever is using this code I'm tying to build.

Comment: I think I know now what your are trying to accomplish; I edited the question accordingly. Please revert and/or clarify if I guessed wrong. Also, what do you want to happen during compilation time for code like `TRIGGER t = choose_trigger(); configExtInt(t, FALLING);`? Warning? Error? You don't care? Depending on the answer to this, you may or may not need to change your code radically.

Comment: @anatolyg
in case t is not INT0, INT1 or INT2 a warning message should appear

Answer (score 1):

[Not sure if I really understood your question correctly]

Assuming the `INTx`s are enums you could use a switch instead those several if-thens.

A decent GCC then would warn you about missing cases:

```
enum Ints
{
  INT0,
  INT1, 
  INT2
}

int main(void)
{
  enum Ints e = ...; /* Initialise to some value here. */

  switch (e)
  {
    case INT0:
      break;

    case INT1:
      break;
  }

  return;
}
```

Compile this using

```
gcc -g  -Wall  -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic  main.c
```

and get:

```
main.c:12:3: warning: enumeration value ‘INT2’ not handled in switch [-Wswitch]
   switch (e)
   ^~~~~~
```